# Access denied for user 'apache'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, centos

I have installed LAMP in CentOS 7

When I placed my files in the default directory (var/www/html in my case)
I receive the following when I access my page:

> Erreur : PB de connexion au serveur mysql de la langue : fr
>   Erreur : PB de connexion � la base de donn�es de la langue : fr
>   Erreur SQL : SELECT * FROM parametres
>   Access denied for user 'apache'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

The following is my config file:

```
$action  = "action";


@error_reporting (E_ALL);
@setlocale(LC_TIME, 'french');


$host     = "localhost";

$user     = "";
$password = ""    ;


 //---> La langue utilisée (fr, en, ar)
 global $lang ;
 $lang             = isset($_REQUEST["lang"])? $_REQUEST["lang"] : "";
 switch($lang)
 {
 case "ar"  :  $lang = "ar" ; break;
 case "en"  : $lang = "en" ; break;
 case "fr"   :  $lang = "fr" ; break;
 default        : $lang = "fr" ; //---> La langue par défaut
 } //Fin switch





 global $lang_param;

$lang_param = array
          (
            //---> principal = TRUE
             "fr" => array(
                           "host"        => "localhost"         ,
                           "db"          => "database_fr"             ,
                           "user"        => "user1"              ,
                           "password"    => ""                  ,
                           "chemin"      => "fr"                ,
                           "description" => "Langue française"  ,
                           "short"       => "Fran&ccedil;ais"          ,
                         ),
                         //---> principal = FALSE
           "en" => array(
                           "host"        => "localhost"         ,
                           "db"          => "database_en"           ,
                           "user"        => "user1"              ,
                           "password"    => ""                  ,
                           "chemin"      => "en"                ,
                           "description" => "Langue anglaise"   ,
                           "short"       => "Anglais"           ,
                         )  ,


             "ar" => array(
                           "host"        => "localhost"         ,
                           "db"          => "database_ar"             ,
                           "user"        => "user1"              ,
                           "password"    => ""                  ,
                           "chemin"      => "ar"                ,
                           "description" => "Langue arabe"  ,
                           "short"       => "Arabe"          ,
                         )           


          ); //Fin $lang_param




//---> Se connecter
$r = @mysql_pconnect($lang_param[$lang]["host"], $lang_param[$lang]       ["user"], $lang_param[$lang]["password"]); 
if ($r==0) 
{
 echo "Erreur : PB de connexion au serveur mysql de la langue :    $lang<br>";
 } //Fsi

  $r = @mysql_select_db($lang_param[$lang]["db"]);
 if ($r==0) {
   echo "Erreur : PB de connexion à la base de données de la langue : $lang<br>";
  } //Fsi
```

How can I gain access for apache@localhost?

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer, and upvote answers that have helped you!

Answer (score 1):

There should be an account defined in the `$user` variable.

Try the root account

`$user='root';`

Please be aware that a root account without password makes your web server unsecured, and set it up as soon as you can

Comment: my root is protected with a strong MDP Thanks but wher i can find the default definition o $user, is not in my code ????

Comment: you mentioned in another comment that you added an account, yes? you can view that at phpmyadmin under accounts

Answer (score 1):

You should create a user:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

And grant privileges on the database you're trying to connect:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON database.*
TO 'user'@'%';
```

After that, you have to fill the variables **$user** and **$password** on your code.

Comment: This is also good, but make sure to give the user a proper access to the following database as well

Comment: thank for your respond . yes i created an user "userx" with full privilege and the problem stil the same.